# Salvar dados de um Jogo em Html5 e Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cache

Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer um "cache" de um projeto meu, pois o jogo funciona normalmente, mas quando atualiza a página, todo progresso é perdido, gostaria de saber como eu consigo fazer esse "cache" para que o progresso seja salvo no navegador do usuário.

Obs:

- por Exemplo o jogo `Cookie Clicker`, que salvava o progresso no navegador.
- Desenvolvi o jogo em `Javascript` e `HTML`
- O progresso do Jogo é colocado em `tag` `<Label>` e gostaria que isso fosse salvo.

Muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: Você precisa salvar as informações num cookie. https://mariovalney.com/como-usar-cookies-com-javascript/

Comment: Se você está usando JS puro siga a sugestão do @MauroAlexandre, caso contrário nos diga que framework está usando.

Comment: Você também pode usar `LocalStorage`, nele cabem mais dados que nos cookies(http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), porém há a possibilidade de versões mais antigas de navegadores não suportar o `LocalStorage`(http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das possíveis soluções seria usar o [localStorage](https://zenorocha.com/html5-local-storage/)

A biblioteca [persist-js](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js) pode, também, ser uma boa alternativa; ela automaticamente usa o localStorage se o browser suportar, ou cookies se o browser for mais antigo.

Comment: Muito Obrigado a todos que comentaram, eu usei o localStorage e funcionou da forma que eu queria!
Att André Neto